# JOIN with date filter for each record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sum DepositAmount if DepositDate is within range of StartDate and EndDate for each PlayerID.

My attempt works but is very inefficient. Player Table with around 25k records and Deposits table with more than 13M records and it takes more than 40 minutes to run.

```
SELECT p.PlayerID, SUM(d.DepositAmount) AS TotalDeposit
FROM Player p
LEFT JOIN Deposits d ON d.PlayerID = p.PlayerID AND (d.DepositDate BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate)
GROUP BY p.PlayerID
```

Is there a better way of doing this in SQL Server?

Player

| PlayerID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55555 | 20200103 | 20210502 |
| 666666 | 20140410 | 20210407 |
| 777777 | 20160107 | 20161012 |

Deposits

| PlayerID | DepositDate | DepositAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55555 | 20210103 | 100 |
| 666666 | 20140412 | 400 |
| 55555 | 20200101 | 100 |
| 777777 | 20160107 | 175 |
| 666666 | 20140405 | 400 |
| 666666 | 20190407 | 400 |
| 777777 | 20160107 | 175 |

Comment: you need to post a query plan  and a CREATE TABLE for all tables

Comment: try using an `inner join` instead of a `left join`.

Comment: @DannySlor `inner join` works slightly better but still doesn't bring runtime to say 3-5 mins

Comment: Can you provide the table schemas and existing keys/indexes and the actual execution plan (PasteThePlan).

Comment: I'm guessing you are probably going to want an index on `Player (PlayerID)` you should have this anyway from the primary key. And depending on how many rows get joined for each `Player` (how many is it?) you want an index either `Deposits (PlayerID, DepositDate) INCLUDE (DepositAmount)` or `Deposits (DepositDate, PlayerID) INCLUDE (DepositAmount)`